# Text paragraph with keywords tagged/highlighted by category

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to achieve below picture functionality in react js. How to achieve this, Please Help. I have a list of differentiated words in a different category, like Organization, Person, Location. I want to separate those words denoting different colors and that category also.

[image: serpate words using some category]

I am done below code but not achieve what I want.

```
<text style={{background:"#A6E22D", borderRadius: "5px", color:'#1E1935'}}> By signing up, you agree to Terms of Service and </text><br/>
```

Comment: This does not appear to be any improvement over when you tried to ask this the first time, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60543946/ (deleted by now.) If your question gets closed, then that means you should make an actual attempt to improve it, not just ask the exact same way again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may implement described feature by breaking your text into blocks of text matching and non-matching to your keywords, than render matching blocks as `<span>` nodes tagged (styled) accordingly:

```js
const { useState } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')

const srcText = `Amazon and Facebook are encouraging their employees in Seattle to stay home after workers for each company tested positive for the novel coronavirus.
Amazon (AMZN) revealed earlier this week that one of its Seattle-based employees has been diagnosed with the virus. On Wednesday, Facebook said a contractor who works at one of its offices in Seattle had tested positive.`

const sampleKeywords = [
  {word: 'Amazon', tag: 'ORG'},
  {word: 'Facebook', tag: 'ORG'},
  {word: 'Seattle', tag: 'GEO'},
  {word: 'earlier this week', tag: 'TIME'},
  {word: 'on Wednesday', tag: 'TIME'}
]

const TaggedText = ({text, keywords}) => {
  const rawKeywords = keywords.map(({word}) => word),
        markedText = text.replace(new RegExp(rawKeywords.join('|'), 'gi'), w => `|${w}|`),
        textBlocks = markedText.split('|').filter(textBlock => textBlock.length != 0)
  return (
    <span style={{lineHeight:'160%'}}>
      {
        textBlocks.map((textBlock,key) => {
          const tag = (keywords.find(({word}) => word.toLowerCase() == textBlock.toLowerCase()) || {tag: null}).tag
          return <span {...{key,...(tag && {tag})}}>{textBlock}{tag && <span className="tagLabel">{tag}</span>}</span>
        })
      }
    </span>
  )
}

render(<TaggedText text={srcText} keywords={sampleKeywords} />, rootNode)
```

```css
span.tagLabel {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: grey;
}

span[tag="ORG"] {
  background: #bf405c;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span[tag="GEO"] {
  background: #3a8a2e;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span[tag="TIME"] {
  background: #822e8a;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```